# Return void or reference to self?

Tags: c++, reference, void, method-chaining

Given the following class:

```
struct Object {
    int x, y;
    void addtoall( int value ){ x += value; y += value; };
    Object& addtoall( int value ){ x += value; y += value; return *this; };
};
```

What is the difference between the two member functions?

I understand that returning a reference to self is required for some operator overloads (e.g: operator+= ), but excluding operator overloading, is it necessary? If not, when would you want or need to return the reference to self as opposed to returning void?

I apologize if this could be found via google-fu, or is a very basic question, but I wasn't sure what exactly to search (and not for lack of trying).

Comment: It allows method chaining, often used as part of a "fluent interface." Those terms are easily Googleable.

Comment: Ah! Hadn't even thought of chaining.

Comment: I'll hold off for a little while before accepting an answer for posterity, but thank you guys for answering so quickly and clearing that up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the difference between the two member functions?

The function returning a reference to the instance can be *chained* when called like

```
Object o;
o.addtoall(5).addtoall(6).addtoall(7);
```

If this is useful depends on the actual use case, but it's often used to develop so called *domain specific language* syntax.

Comment: It would be interesting mentioning the [_named parameter idiom_](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Named_Parameter), a good example of use of such a technique.

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that returning a reference to self is required for some operator overloads (e.g: operator+=)

No, it's not. Many people (including myself) advocate that such operators should be declared to return `void`, most notably `operator=`, the chaining (or expression reuse) of which actually obscures code in the vast majority of cases it is used. We do it for (unfortunate) convention, only.

What's chaining? Precisely what returning such references is intended to allow:

```
std::string{"asdf"}.append(c1).append(c2)
```

[`append` returns `string&`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append), unsurprisingly. While mildly useful for `string` (`append({c1, c2})` is more concise), it's pointless in most other cases (such as yours, where we could just add two `int`s instead of calling the method twice).

Comment: +1 because for your _No, it's not_ that forces me to read the standard once more. Thank you, never thought about that, but it makes perfectly sense.